# Double Hashing efficiency with word dictionary

Tags: java, dictionary, hash, double-hashing

Simply put I have a dictionary of words and I'm adding them to a hash table.

I am using Double Hashing (not the conventional method) and the following is yielding the best result.

```
    public static int getHashKey(String word) {

        int index = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i<word.length(); i++){

            index += Math.pow(4,  i)*((int)word.charAt(i));
            index = index % size;
        }
        return index;
    }

    public static int getDoubleHashKey(String word) {

        int jump = 1;

        for(int i = 0; i<word.length(); i++){

            jump = jump * word.charAt(i);
            jump = jump % size;
        }
        return jump;

    }
```

This is giving me 127,000 collisions. I also have a 2 fold prime hash table size and it cannot be changed.

Is there any way the Double Hashing algorithm can be improved? (Either of the 2 methods above).

I know it depends on what we are storing in the hash table etc. but is there any intuitive method or some tips that apply more generally so I can avoid a couple more collisions.

Comment: take first hash as `word.hashcode()` and for second hash iterate through your implementations

Comment: Whats the valid of size, and also, instead of starting from 1, why not have jump start from a large prime?

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys.

@JigarJoshi I'm trying to avoid Java API for the moment

Comment: @AmirAfghani The Array size is 216555, but I am limited to twice this for hash table size. Changing initial jump size to a larger prime made very little difference, but it never occurred to me so thanks for that!

Comment: I have nothing to back it up, but I think you should compute `jump % size` only once, outside of the loop. Intuitively, if you compute the modulo at each iteration, you are more likely to find the same values of `jump` as they belong to a smaller space.

Comment: Numbers too large for int to hold if I mod outside the loop. I could change to BigInteger class but the effort.

Comment: And then ? It would just overflow, which is no big deal as long as you replace `jump` in the right interval at the end

Comment: See my updated answer with more accurate figures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran a little Scala program on a dictionary of about 336 531 entries. There are significantly less collisions for the version 2 (118 142) than for the version 1 (305 431). Notice that the version 2 is close to an optimal number of collisions because 118 142 + 216 555 = 334 697, so 334 697/336 531 = 99,46% of values used in the 0-216555 range. Using the modulo **outside** the loop **does** improve your hash method.

```
import scala.io.Source

object Hash extends App {
    val size = 216555
    def doubleHashKey1(word: String) = {
        var jump = 1;
        for (ch <- word) {
            jump = jump * ch;
            jump = jump % size;
        }
        jump
    }

    def doubleHashKey2(word: String) = {
        var jump = 1;
        for (ch <- word) jump = jump * ch;
        jump % size;
    }

    def countCollisions(words: Set[String], hashFun: String => Int) = words.size - words.map(hashFun).size
    def readDictionary(path: String) = Source.fromFile(path).getLines.toSet

    val dict = readDictionary("words.txt")
    println(countCollisions(dict,doubleHashKey1))
    println(countCollisions(dict,doubleHashKey2))
}
```

For handling the integer overflow, you must use a different (but trivial to implement) way to compute the modulo in order to return positive values. Another test to do would be to see if the collisions are statically well distributed.